# Wrap string with hyperlink - jQuery & RegExp

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="subjectList">
    <p>PHM315 Pharmacy Practice 2
        <br/>PHM101 Introduction to Pharmacy
        <br/>PHM215 Pharmacy Practice 1
        <br/>PHM490 Rural Pharmacy Practice</p>
</div>
```

I'd like to search for any string which matches the following pattern:

```
/([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9])/g
```

And wrap that matched text with a url.

Essentially,

```
<p>PHM315 Pharmacy Practice 2
```

becomes:

```
<p><a href="/PHM315">PHM315</a> Pharmacy Practice 2
```

I almost have this working, using this jQuery

```
var replaceSubjectCode = "<a href=\"/subjects/$1.html\">$1</a>";
var str = $('.subjectList p').html();
str = str.replace(/([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9])/g, new RegExp(replaceSubjectCode));
$('.subjectList p').html(str);
```

However it outputs the following:

```
<div class="subjectList">
 <p>/<a href="/subjects/PMH315">PHM315</a>/ Pharmacy Practice 2<br/>
```

Note the additional "/" outside the < a > tags.

Any assistance in removing these forward slashes would be greatly appreciated. I have tried running a RegExp replace using ///g  - but I cannot seem to get it to ignore the hyperlink.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qWP43/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **remove** the call for a **RegExp** Object in your replacement, which is the reason you have `/` .. `/` delimiters surrounding your captured match `$1`. You can change it to the following:

```
str = str.replace(/([A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3})/g, replaceSubjectCode);
```

See [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWP43/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `.replace()` is supposed to be either a string or function, not a RegExp object as you have there; it's likely to have been cast to a string and this causes some issues ... to be honest, I was surprised it even worked.

You could use this to perform the replacement instead:

```
$('.subjectList p').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace(/[A-Z]{3}\d{3}/g, function($0) {
        return $0.link('/subjects/' + $0 + '.html');
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/xogekona/1/)

It uses [`String.prototype.link()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/link) to replace the found matches; this logic is then wrapped into a single [`.html(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) to update the document.